# The same variable shared between double pointer and single pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double-pointer

Good evening,
quick question regarding the following code:

```
// Start of main
int i,j;
int row,col;

printf("Enter the values for row and col:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&row,&col);
int **arr=(int**)malloc(row*(sizeof(int*)));

for(i=0; i<row; i++)
{
 *(arr+i) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
}

// .. code after this snippet
```

Why am I able to use the variable `arr` as a pointer to a pointer and then re-use it as a pointer inside the for loop ?? Why do I not have to create two seperate variables ?

Comment: A pointer is a pointer is a pointer. It doesn't matter what it points to, it's still a pointer.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` and friends in C!

Comment: Also, remember that you can use array indexing syntax with pointers too, and that `*(arr + i)` is equivalent to `arr[i]`, which often is more intuitive (and a little less to write).

Comment: What do you mena by "re-use"? You dereference it, but you can also assign a new value. You seem to missed some basic concepts - no offence! May I recommend to read a C book? Pointers are used in (almost) every non-trivial C program, so you really have to understand them well. Every good book treats this subject en detail.

Comment: Olaf - It so happens that I'm actually reading "C Programming : A modern approach 2nd Edition" by K.N. King right now so thank you for your concern about my basics ... I'm also aware how important pointers are so thank you for that too. My confusion has risen by array notation and pointer arithmetic equivalent to it. I'm trying to find every possible scenario where one equals another because currently it's a big chaos in my head. Other than that I'm okay with most of the basics :)

Comment: You shouldn't allocate pointer-to-pointer lookup tables like these anyway. If that book told you to do so, you may have to consider burning it with fire. Instead, allocate a real 2D array in adjacent memory. `int (*arr)[row][col] = malloc(sizeof int[row][col]);`.

Comment: Lundin - The code above wasn't an example in the book, it was my own experimenation combined with some research on stackoverflow. I wanted to create a 2D array with variable length of columns, I don't see why that method is a bad idea ? Also in relation to the line of code you wrote, I don't think the sizeof operator is going to work for 2D array properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not "reusing" `arr` as both a pointer to pointer and as a pointer.  `arr` has type `int **`, but then you do some pointer arithmetic and dereference the pointer with `*(arr + i)`, and that expression has type `int *`.

Also, as mentioned by Joachim in the comments, `*(arr + i)` is equivalent to `arr[i]`.  Using this notation makes it more clear exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Okay, I see my confusion now, I thought that after declaring and defining an int **arr then later on in the code I can only de-refference it to **arr, not, *arr. Thank you, upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `for` loop, you are *not* using `arr` as a **pointer-to-an-int**; you are using `*(arr+i)` as a **pointer-to-an-int**, which is consistent with dereferencing `arr`, which is a **pointer-to-a-pointer-to-an-int**.